# Toggle class don't remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, toggleclass

I'm trying to make an `article` add a class while a menu is open.
So, when the button is clicked, this will show the menu and also certain item (the `article`) should get the class `padded`, and when we press the button again, the class `padded` must be removed.

Now, it's adding the class, but not removing it when the button is clicked again

http://www.bootply.com/xcfWMYveNe

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this jQuery method called "**toggleClass**"

```
$('.tab-pane.active').toggleClass("padded");
```

Comment: Damn, same answer but you drew first :)

Answer (score 2):

Just do this :

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.data-holder .tab-pane.active').toggleClass("padded");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo, and I changed one bit.

See [this updated bootply](http://www.bootply.com/BUIOSP4Mxq)

Relevant js:

```
  if ($('.tab-pane.active.padded').length > 0){
     $('.tab-pane.active').removeClass("padded");
  }else {
     $('.tab-pane.active').addClass("padded");
  };
```

Comment: `toggleClass` is much shorter and much more elegant.